# SQL query to join tables - where one table's datetime does not match the other ones

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Joined just to ask this because it is killing me :) Great forum with a lot of great minds!

I simply need to join these two tables, i can only join them on date and time no other columns are available.

Table 1 has for example following columns

**Film -----------------Datetime……………………………Duration(minutes)**

TITANIC------------2016-01-01 01:00:00-----------------60

Armageddon---------2016-01-01 02:00:00-----------------60

**Table 2 has following columns**

**Date----------------Time**

2016-01-01……….01:00:00

2016-01-01……….01:01:00

2016-01-01……….01:02:00

2016-01-01……….01:03:00

…and so on

Table 2 contains info for every minute but table one only one specific time and date per event. so i need to match for every minute in table two with what i got from table one.

Any ideas? i'll take anything that works :) btw sorry for the formatting!

Edit:
Desired result would be something like

TITANIC------------2016-01-01 01:00:00-----------------60

TITANIC------------2016-01-01 01:01:00-----------------60

TITANIC------------2016-01-01 01:02:00-----------------60

Armageddon---------2016-01-01 02:00:00-----------------60

Armageddon---------2016-01-01 02:01:00-----------------60

Armageddon---------2016-01-01 02:02:00-----------------60

And so on...

Comment: Can you please elaborate what the result would look like with your current sample data?

Comment: The duration would be looped to increase datetime with one minute, for the as many minutes as the duration value has. Or add another column as "Endtdatetime" for example (datetime_column+duration_column) AS Endtdatetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to make some assumptions as you haven't outlined the table structure.

Your film table is of the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Films ([Film] NVARCHAR(128), [DateTime] DATETIME, Duration INT)
GO
```

Your Date/Time values table is of the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE DateTimeValues ([Date] DATE, [Time] TIME)
GO
```

Lets insert your values:

```
--Insert Values for Films
INSERT INTO Films
VALUES  ('TITANIC', '2016-01-01T01:00:00', 60),
        ('Armageddon', '2016-01-01 02:00:00', 60)

GO

--Insert Values for every minute of 2016-01-01
DECLARE @DATETIMEBEGIN DATETIME
SET @DATETIMEBEGIN = '2016-01-01' 
DECLARE @DATETIMEEND DATETIME  
SELECT @DATETIMEEND = '2016-01-02' 

;WITH CTE AS (SELECT DATEADD(day, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATETIMEBEGIN)) DateTimeValues
              UNION  ALL
              SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, DateTimeValues) AS DateTimeValues
              FROM CTE
              WHERE DateTimeValues < @DATETIMEEND
              )
INSERT INTO DateTimeValues
SELECT  CONVERT(DATE, DateTimeValues) "Date",
        CONVERT(TIME, DateTimeValues) "Time"
FROM    CTE
OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 0)
GO
```

Lets make it simple and lets caluclate the start time/end time for each film according to the duration. The query you will need for your desired output is:

```
;WITH CTEFilms AS
(
    SELECT  Film,
            CONVERT(DATE, [DateTime]) "Date",
            CONVERT(TIME, [DateTime]) "StartTime",
            CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(MINUTE,Duration,[DateTime])) "EndTime",
            Duration
    FROM    Films
)

SELECT      f.Film,
            CAST(dtv."Date" AS DATETIME) + dtv."Time" "DateTime",
            Duration
FROM        CTEFilms f
INNER JOIN  DateTimeValues dtv
            ON f.[Date] = dtv.[Date]
            AND dtv.[Time] >= f.StartTime
            AND dtv.[Time] < f.EndTime
ORDER BY    Film, Time
```

Your Results:

```
Film        DateTime                Duration
Armageddon  2016-01-01 02:00:00.000 60
Armageddon  2016-01-01 02:01:00.000 60
Armageddon  2016-01-01 02:02:00.000 60
Armageddon  2016-01-01 02:03:00.000 60
Armageddon  2016-01-01 02:04:00.000 60
...
Armageddon  2016-01-01 02:55:00.000 60
Armageddon  2016-01-01 02:56:00.000 60
Armageddon  2016-01-01 02:57:00.000 60
Armageddon  2016-01-01 02:58:00.000 60
Armageddon  2016-01-01 02:59:00.000 60
TITANIC     2016-01-01 01:00:00.000 60
TITANIC     2016-01-01 01:01:00.000 60
TITANIC     2016-01-01 01:02:00.000 60
TITANIC     2016-01-01 01:03:00.000 60
TITANIC     2016-01-01 01:04:00.000 60
...
TITANIC     2016-01-01 01:55:00.000 60
TITANIC     2016-01-01 01:56:00.000 60
TITANIC     2016-01-01 01:57:00.000 60
TITANIC     2016-01-01 01:58:00.000 60
TITANIC     2016-01-01 01:59:00.000 60
```

Answer (score 1):

convert the table 2 date and time to a datetime and see if it is between table 1 datetime and datetime + duration.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table1 t1
        JOIN table2 t2 ON CAST(t2.Date AS DATETIME)
                          + CAST(t2.Time AS DATETIME) >= t1.Datetime
                          AND CAST(t2.Date AS DATETIME)
                          + CAST(t2.Time AS DATETIME) < DATEADD(MIN,
                                                              t1.Duration,
                                                              t1.Datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Eddie B, you did not give out your table structure, i.e. column data types, so I just come up with the following assumed code/data

```
use tempdb
drop table dbo.t1, dbo.t2;
create table dbo.T1 (film varchar(10), dt datetime, duration int)
create table dbo.T2 (dt varchar(10), tm varchar(10));
go

-- populate the tables with SOME sample data

insert into dbo.T1(film, dt, duration)
values ('Titanic', '2016-01-01 01:00:00', 5), ('Amageddon', '2016-01-01 02:00:00', 4)

insert into dbo.T2 (dt, tm)
values 
  ('2016-01-01', '01:00:00')
,  ('2016-01-01', '01:01:00')
,  ('2016-01-01', '01:02:00')
,  ('2016-01-01', '01:03:00')
,  ('2016-01-01', '01:04:00')
,  ('2016-01-01', '01:05:00')

,  ('2016-01-01', '02:00:00')
,  ('2016-01-01', '02:01:00')
,  ('2016-01-01', '02:02:00')
,  ('2016-01-01', '02:03:00')
,  ('2016-01-01', '02:04:00')
,  ('2016-01-01', '02:05:00')

,  ('2016-01-01', '03:00:00');

go

-- here is the result
select t1.film, [DateTime]= convert(datetime,   t2.dt + ' ' + t2.tm), t1.duration
from dbo.t1 
inner join dbo.t2
on convert(datetime,   t2.dt + ' ' + t2.tm) >= t1.dt
and convert(datetime,   t2.dt + ' ' + t2.tm) <= dateadd(minute, t1.duration, t1.dt)
go
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: WOW, worked like a charm. Although i am having some issues joining because t2 has a time range between 02-26 hours and not your normal 00-00, weird i know. How would i go about to get around this? t1 has the normal 00-00h, update or select doesn't matter...